# Beamer - Multiple Authors - Formatting the title page

Tags: beamer, titles

I have 4 authors for the beamer presentation. I tried to put them but its not properly aligned.  Here is a snapshot:
[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\author[Subham Soni S. \& Mithun C.K. \& Karthikeyan \& Shantikumar L.]
{%
   \texorpdfstring{
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            Subham Soni S.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            Mithun C.K.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            Karthikeyan\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            Shantikumar L.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
        \end{columns}
   }
   {John Doe \& Jane Doe}
}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If the authors can be arranged vertically I feel that would be better and down below in the pdf in the 3 boxes , the author names are concatenated in the first box, I saw in of the beam ppts that the authors were separated in another row. How to do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is another possible layout:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\RBox[1]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,align=center,] {#1};%
}  
\author[Subham Soni S. \& Mithun C.K. \& Karthikeyan \& Shantikumar L.]
{%
   \texorpdfstring{
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Subham Soni S.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Mithun C.K.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
        \end{columns}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Karthikeyan\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Shantikumar L.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
        \end{columns}
        \vspace{-0.3cm}
        \begin{columns}
          \column{0.3\linewidth}
          \raggedleft
            \includegraphics[width=0.7cm]{pecemblem}
            \vspace{-4.8cm}
            \column{0.6\linewidth}
            \raggedright
            Department of CSE\\[1.1ex]
            PEC\\
            \vspace{-4.8cm}
        \end{columns}
   }
   {John Doe \& Jane Doe}
}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding these lines to the definition of `\RBox`

```
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcommand\RBox[1]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,align=center,double copy shadow={opacity=0.3,shadow xshift=1ex,shadow yshift=-0.5ex,left color = brown!40,right color = magenta!80},left color=blue!50,right color=green!50 ] {#1};%
```

gives

[image]

<sub>I am bad too in color choice :(</sub>

Answer (score 10):

You can use only two columns instead of four; the leftmost column will contain the authors, and the rightmost one, the logo:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\RBox[1]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,align=center,] {#1};%
}  

\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{size={\fontsize{3pt}{4pt}\selectfont}}
\author[Subham \& Mithun \& Karthikeyan \& Shantikumar]
{%
   \texorpdfstring{
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ctanlion}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Subham Soni S.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}\\[0.5ex]
            \RBox{Karthikeyan\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}\\[0.5ex]
            \RBox{Mithun C.K.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}\\[0.5ex]
            \RBox{Shantikumar L.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
        \end{columns}
   }
   {Subham Soni S., Karthikeyanm, Shantikumar L.,  Mithun C.K.}
}
\title{Work Culture}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also the line

```
\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{size={\fontsize{3pt}{4pt}\selectfont}}
```

to reduce the font for the authors in the footline so they fit in the available space.

<sub>CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.</sub>

Comment: @subhamsoni One frame for all the authors or each author in a separate frame. Anything else? Please mention all the requirements from the beginning.

Comment: One frame per each and if possible all the authors in one column vertically on the right and a image on the left below the title

Comment: @subhamsoni Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Yup Got it. This is what I wanted to do :). Actually by myself, but I had no idea how to do it :(