# Three author names and affiliations in the same line

Tags: beamer, presentations

I would like to have three authors in the first presentation page in the same line.

How is it possible to make it.

Here I try to reproduce [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163216/168831) example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\RBox[1]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,align=center,] {#1};%
}  
\author[Subham Soni S. \& Mithun C.K. \& Karthikeyan \& Shantikumar L.]
{%
   \texorpdfstring{
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Subham Soni S.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Mithun C.K.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
        \end{columns}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Karthikeyan\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Shantikumar L.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
        \end{columns}
        \vspace{-0.3cm}
        \begin{columns}
          \column{0.3\linewidth}
          \raggedleft
            \includegraphics[width=0.7cm]{pecemblem}
            \vspace{-4.8cm}
            \column{0.6\linewidth}
            \raggedright
            Department of CSE\\[1.1ex]
            PEC\\
            \vspace{-4.8cm}
        \end{columns}
   }
   {John Doe \& Jane Doe}
}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I can reproduce it for three authors but to be in the same line?

Answer (score 3):

To place three instead of two columns besides each other, you need to make them a bit smaller:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\RBox[1]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,align=center,] {#1};%
}  
\author[Subham Soni S. \& Mithun C.K. \& Karthikeyan \& Shantikumar L.]
{%
   \texorpdfstring{
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.3\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Subham Soni S.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{\tiny subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
            \column{.3\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Mithun C.K.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{\tiny subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
            \column{.3\linewidth}
            \centering
            \RBox{Karthikeyan\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{\tiny subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
        \end{columns}
        \vspace{-0.3cm}
        \begin{columns}
          \column{0.3\linewidth}
          \raggedleft
            \includegraphics[width=0.7cm]{example-image-duck}
            \vspace{-4.8cm}
            \column{0.6\linewidth}
            \raggedright
            Department of CSE\\[1.1ex]
            PEC\\
            \vspace{-4.8cm}
        \end{columns}
   }
   {John Doe \& Jane Doe}
}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried it here [link](https://www.overleaf.com/18810134xvvggqtxxknv#/70700274/) but I receive an error

Comment: @Stiar replace the image by one of yours.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\RBox[1]{%
    \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,align=center,] {#1};%
}  
\author[Subham Soni S. \& Mithun C.K. \& Karthikeyan \& Shantikumar L.]
{%
\texorpdfstring{\centering
    \RBox{Subham Soni S.\\
        \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{\tiny subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
\qquad
    \RBox{Mithun C.K.\\
        \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{\tiny subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
\qquad
    \RBox{Karthikeyan\\
        \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{\tiny subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}\\
\vspace{1.5cm}
\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{\raggedleft
    \includegraphics[width=0.7cm]{example-image-duck}}
\qquad
\parbox{0.6\linewidth}{\today\\%
            Department of CSE\\[1.1ex]
            PEC}%
    }{John Doe \& Jane Doe}%
}
\date[\today]{}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

an alternative:

- used only three authors :-)
- for placement of the authors is used `tabularx` environment with three columns
- font size of authors (\footnotesize) is determined by definition of RBox

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \useoutertheme{infolines}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{tabularx}

  \newcommand\RBox[1]{%
    \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,align=center,font=\footnotesize] {#1};%
  }
  \author[Subham Soni S. \& Mithun C.K. \& Karthikeyan]
  {\texorpdfstring{\centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
      \RBox{Subham Soni S.\\
      \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
      &
      \RBox{Mithun C.K.\\
      \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
      &
      \RBox{Karthikeyan\\
      \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}}
                  \end{tabularx}\\[5ex]
      \centering
                  \begin{tabular}{c @{\qquad} m{22ex}}
      \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}
      &
      \today\newline
      Department of CSE\medskip\newline
      PEC\newline
                  \end{tabular}
  }{}
  }
  \date[\today]{}
  \title{Work Culture}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \titlepage
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]